# force HTTPS only on non www

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Current code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I need to redirect non www trafffic to HTTPS www, but need to leave direct accessed www trafic without enforcing HTTPS.

So I tried this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

But i'm getting "too many redirects" and dont know why.
index.php comes from a laravel instalation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 2 VirtualHosts, I am using your redirect rules:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.test.com
    ServerAlias test.com

    [... OTHER CONFIGURATION ...]

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]        
</VirtualHost

Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.test.com
    ServerAlias test.com

    [... OTHER CONFIGURATION ...]        
</VirtualHost>
```

**You ask for `http://test.com` --> https://test.com/$1**

```
because of `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$`
```

**You ask for `http://ANYTHING` --> https://test.com/$1**

because of `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`.  Why?  Because of the `[OR]` option.  It should be an '[AND]', which is implicit.  So remove the `[OR]`.  Same thing for the second one.

Also you are contradicting your self in the second group of directives.  It says:

- it is www.test.com
- **OR test.com**
- not a directory
- not a file
- go to index.php

---

You said you want to redirect non-www requests to https.

Therefore you want:

- http://www.test.com  --> stays in `<VirtualHost *:80>`
- http://test.com      --> redirect to `<VirtualHost *:443>`
- https://www.test.com --> in `<VirtualHost *:443>`
- https://test.com     --> in `<VirtualHost *:443>`

This configuration will do that:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.test.com
    ServerAlias test.com

    [... OTHER CONFIGURATION ...]

    RewriteEngine On

    # http://test.com --> redirect to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Everything else stays in <VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Default page index.php, avoid 404
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</VirtualHost

Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.test.com
    ServerAlias test.com

    [... OTHER CONFIGURATION ...]        

    # Default page index.php, avoid 404
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</VirtualHost>
```